# How can I use local constants in the function definitions of ezplot?

Tags: matlab

Based on the reference examples [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html), I cannot seem to use variables in my workspace as constants in my function expressions. For example, trying to do:

```
ezplot('theta * (1 x y) - 0.5', 0,8,-5,4);
```

Where theta is a `3 x 1`  vector results in the error

```
theta * [1;x;y] - 0.5 cannot be plotted in the xy-plane.
```

Is there any way to get around this restriction?

Comment: What is the relation between `x` and `y` in `(1 x y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `theta` is `1 x 3` (it cannot be `3 x 1`) then you can use

```
ezplot(@(x,y) theta * [1;x;y] - 0.5, [0,8,-5,4]);
```

Note that you cannot refer to another variable in workspace when you are defining the function as a string. You need to create an anonymous function. Also the ranges for plotting are not separate arguments. You need to pass a vector of length 4.